# How to delete row in PostgreSQL using Python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to delete the whole row when user enters the id. If it matches, I completely delete whole row from table.

```
@staticmethod
    def close_account(value):
        check()
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            if rows is None:
                print("Sorry It's an Empty.............. ")
                return True
            elif rows[0] == value:
                del_row = "Delete From customer where id = value"
                cur.execute(del_row)
                return True
```

It shows error in del_row that:

> value is unable to resolve column value

Even if I enter the id = 1 it also does not delete the row.

Comment: You need to parameterize that statement. Right now, Postgres thinks you have a *column* called `value` and you are comparing it to `id`. Since the column `value` does not exist you get the "unable to resolve column value" error.

Comment: How to assign parameter?

Comment: query must be

    del_row = f"Delete From customer where id = '{value}'"

Comment: it's still not working, this time it not show error but it also not remove data

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `id` attribute is a string, change this line:

```
del_row = "Delete From customer where id = value"
```

to:

```
del_row = "Delete From customer where id = %s" % value
```

The way you have it, the database is trying to delete `DELETE FROM customer WHERE id="value"`, whereas your goal is to replace `value` with the function parameter (e.g. `DELETE FROM customer WHERE id="123"`

**Disclaimer**: This solution makes your code susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: Values should not be passed into the query using string formatting, please recommend query parameters instead. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

Comment: I'm aware it makes it susceptible to SQL injection, but I doubt the OP is worried about security or performance at this point. I don't get why would you downvote the answer, it actually answers the question. At most, it's not the most suitable solution. I added a disclaimer in the end

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. Primarily you're not passing a value in for the `id = X` condition in your query, so you'll need to do that - preferably using a [parameterized query](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters), that looks like this:

```py
del_row = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE id = %s"
cur.execute(del_row, (1))
```

Your second problem is the assumption that the row ID is `1`, when this may not be the case. If your `ID` field is auto incrementing, then it may be far greater than that. If your original query is returning the ID as a column, you should be able to retrieve the row ID using something like:

```py
row[0]
```

Which, when passed into the first code block, means you end up with something like this:

```py
@staticmethod
def close_account(value):
    check()
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        if rows is None:
            print("Sorry It's an Empty.............. ")
            return True
        elif rows[0] == value:
            del_row = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE id = %s"
            cur.execute(del_row, row[0])
            return True
```

Comment: You should use parenthesis where it makes sense, and also make sure to close dittos, or you are susceptible to syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
"Delete From customer where id = %s" % value
```

will possibly get you what you want. On the other hand, it's a bad idea to programatically walk through all rows of the database to find a single one to delete, but I guess there are even bigger fish to fry first...

Comment: It's a bad idea to format the string like this using Python's string formatting as it makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead query parameterization should be used. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters